# how to add axes to 3D histogram (rgl)

Tags: r, histogram, rgl

I build a histogram in R using the `rgl` package.

```
library(rgl)
rgl.bg(col="#cccccc")
x<-rnorm(2500)
y<-rnorm(2500)
hist3d(x, y, alpha=0.8, nclass=10, scale=30)
```

[image]

How can I add an axis with labels on the plot?

**Update**

Solution:

```
axes3d(c('x','y','z'))
title3d('','','xlab','ylab','zlab')
```

source code `hist3d` is located in the `demo(hist3d)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add:

```
axes3d()
```

In case someone tries to run the above code: it is not self-contained, you need to copy the code for `hist3d` and `binplot` from ?hist3d.